# Trying to learn basic for loop and/or if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I have just started to learn python and I wonder what is wrong with
this for loop and/or if statement.

I am trying to loop through a list of words and if I find
a word "right" I want to replace it with the word "left".

```
def left_join(phrases):                
"""                 
    Join strings and replace "right" to "left"            
"""               

    mlist = list(phrases) 

    for word in mlist:

        if word == "right":
             word = "left"

    output = ','.join(mlist)
    return output    

phrases = ("left", "right", "left", "stop")
left_join(phrases)
```

I am supposed to get this

`"left,left,left,stop"`

but I get

`"left,right,left,stop"`

So "right" is not replaced with "left". Why?

Comment: `word = left` changes the variable `word`, but it doesn't change the list `mlist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [official documentation on for loop](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement),

> An iterator is created for the result of the expression_list. The suite is then executed once for each item provided by the iterator, in the order of ascending indices.

So the `mlist` does not change, only `word` is changed here

Comment: Thank you! Btw can the one who downvoted explain why so i can learn to ask better questions in the future?

Comment: Did not downvote, but I would imagine there's a lot of people with very little patience for beginner questions.

Comment: @Untitled123 Why do they bother to read them then?? My title was very clear about this being a beginner question.

Comment: There's a lot of questions that have been asked uncountably many times and can be easily googled (so it's super low effort). While I would not consider this one to be like that (since it's not obvious at all), there are others who just try to downvote these questions into oblivion, so they are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
def left_join(phrases):                
    """                 
         Join strings and replace "right" to "left"            
    """               

    mlist = list(phrases) 

    for i  in range(len(mlist)):

        if mlist[i] == "right":
            mlist[i] = "left"

    output = ','.join(mlist)
    return output    

phrases = ("left", "right", "left", "stop")
output = left_join(phrases)
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question was more about why that particular code did not work. I had figured out this solution before and had even found this one left_join = lambda p: ",".join(p).replace('right', 'left') But i couldnt figure out why the code i posted did not work and to get a response to that i would learn something about python